# Multiple Modal Dialog Cause Browser unable to load

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am facing some issue on how to allow multiple modal dialog to run on a web.
When i include 2 modal dialog in my HTML code, the web page was unable to load.

Basically this is my HTML code

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>New User?
                    <a id="btn_signup_now" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" href="#mySignUp" data-backdrop="true">
                     Sign Up For Free Now
                        </a>
                </label>
            </div>


<div id="mySignUp" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <asp:Button runat="server" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" Text="*"/>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalSignUp">Candidate Sign Up</h4>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be closer to this:

You are missing many elements that are necessary for a modal to work and have elements that **may** also be breaking it. You need this `target="#mySignUp"` to call the `modal` and you're also missing the `<div class="modal-content">` and `<div class="modal-header">` (and footer `<div class="modal-footer">` if you feel it's needed. When I tested it your **hide** class broke it but that may be specific to what you are doing.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>New User? <a id="btn_signup_now" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" target="#mySignUp" href="#mySignUp" data-backdrop="true"> Sign Up For Free Now</a></label>
</div>
<div id="mySignUp" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalSignUp">Candidate Sign Up</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button runat="server" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" Text="*" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```